# Is it valid to use only modify not "modify column" in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax, alter-table

I'm starting to study MySQL and I found in one of my resources the use of the command:

```
Alter table tableName modify(....)
```

Instead of using 'modify column'
It it valid to use it and if it's I want some.

I tried to search about it but I found nothing. The only information is that could be an older version

Comment: You said you couldn't find it when you searched. Isn't the MySQL documentation the first place you looked?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [`alter table` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html), you'll see that when using the `modify` directive, the `column` keyword is optional:

```
| MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

In layman's terms - you can either use it or not, it makes no difference.